# Identify newly created file with Dropbox /delta API

Tags: dropbox-api

I am exploring dropbox delta API to identify changes happened to dropbox account. When i analyze the response, it is giving similar kind of response to modified and newly created file. Is there any flag to differentiate the newly added file from modified file?

If i just want to check just newly added file, i had to check existing files in my database which is pretty inefficient to compare revisions for each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Files that are newly created and files that have been modified look the same via the `/delta` API. If you want to identify new files specifically, you should check whether you're already aware of a file at that path. This should be a very efficient lookup. For example, if you're using a SQL database, something like `SELECT 1 FROM FILES WHERE path = '/path/to/file.txt'`.

Presumably, you're about to store the path in your database, so there may be a way to combine both into a single operation. For example, in Redis, you could do `SADD files "/path/to/file.txt"`, which will add the new path to the set of existing paths and return either 1 or 0, for when the path is new and when it already existed, respectively.

Comment: i understood the approach of looking in database. But the problem i see is, i cannot identify if a file is moved from one directory to another one. How can i detect this scenario?

Comment: There's no reliable way to detect a move. A possible heuristic is to look for a delete and a create that are close together in time where the created file has the same content as the deleted file.